# How to access .env variables in AppDelegate.m from Flutter applications?

Tags: flutter, dart

as instructed from a similar problem [Hide Google Maps API key from source control in a Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57575973/hide-google-maps-api-key-from-source-control-in-a-flutter-app/59590990#59590990)

AppDelegate.m

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     NSString* mapsApiKey = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment][@"FLUTTER_GMAPS_API_KEY"];
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey: mapsApiKey];
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

If i change provideApiKey to @"theApiKeyImTryingToHide" everything works fine.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: no i haven't, sorry

Comment: I don't know if it's something you looking for, but I [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61748387/10871399) to the question, that you referenced. Hope it helps)

Comment: @tatusDn this is actually what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

I found this question by searching answer for the react-native lib
maybe for someone it can be useful.

so, to read variable from env in RN you have to add

```
NSString *mapsApiKey = [ReactNativeConfig envFor:@"GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY"];
[GMSServices provideAPIKey: mapsApiKey];
```

into top of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in **AppDelegate.m** file
and firstly don't forget to import

`#import "ReactNativeConfig.h"`

`ReactNativeConfig` provide `GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY`

Comment: This worked nicely for me and is the proper use of `react-native-config`.

See the [Android equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912959/access-environment-variable-in-react-native-androidmanifest-xml) so you can define your API_KEY in one place for both platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check from your shell if your env variable FLUTTER_GMAPS_API_KEY is being set properly ?

Also check this AppDelegate.m file from the official maps repo if it helps

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m

Comment: Yes i have set it properly, but turns out in newer flutter versions there isn't an AppDelegate.m file anymore so I'm afraid this question isn't really relevant. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use your maps api key in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `AppDelegate.swift` files from the same `.env` file using the [flutter_config](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_config) package. For details refer to this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65448051/2532763